# How to preserve an ampersand (&) while using FOR XML PATH on SQL 2005

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

Are there any tricks for preventing SQL Server from entitizing chars like &, <, and >?  I'm trying to output a URL in my XML file but SQL wants to replace any '&' with '`&amp;`'

Take the following query:

```
SELECT 'http://foosite.com/' + RTRIM(li.imageStore)
        + '/ImageStore.dll?id=' + RTRIM(li.imageID)
        + '&raw=1&rev=' + RTRIM(li.imageVersion) AS imageUrl
FROM ListingImages li
FOR XML PATH ('image'), ROOT ('images'), TYPE
```

The output I get is like this (&s are entitized):

```
<images>
  <image>
    <imageUrl>http://foosite.com/pics4/ImageStore.dll?id=7E92BA08829F6847&amp;raw=1&amp;rev=0</imageUrl>
  </image>
</images>
```

What I'd like is this (&s are not entitized):

```
<images>
  <image>
    <imageUrl>http://foosite.com/pics4/ImageStore.dll?id=7E92BA08829F6847&raw=1&rev=0</imageUrl>
  </image>
</images>
```

How does one prevent SQL server from entitizing the '&'s into '`&amp;`'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What SQL Server generates is correct. What you expect to see is not well-formed XML. The reason is that `&` character signifies the start of an entity reference, such as `&amp;`. See the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references) for more information.

When your XML parser parses this string out of XML, it will understand the `&amp;` entity references and return the text back in the form you want. So the internal format in the XML file should not cause a problem to you unless you're using a buggy XML parser, or trying to parse it manually (in which case your current parser code is effectively buggy at the moment with respect to the XML specification).

Answer (score 71):

There are situations where a person may not want well formed XML - the one I (and perhaps the original poster) encountered was using the For XML Path technique to return a single field list of 'child' items via a recursive query.  More information on this technique is here (specifically in the 'The blackbox XML methods' section):
[Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

For my situation, seeing 'H&E' (a pathology stain) transformed into 'well formed XML' was a real disappointment.  Fortunately, I found a solution... the following page helped me solve this issue relatively easily and without having re-architect my recursive query or add additional parsing at the presentation level (for this as well for as other/future situations where my child-rows data fields contain reserved XML characters): [Handling Special Characters with FOR XML PATH](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path/)

---

EDIT: code below from the referenced blog post.

```
select
  stuff(
     (select ', <' + name + '>'
     from sys.databases
     where database_id > 4
     order by name
     for xml path(''), root('MyString'), type
     ).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)')
   , 1, 2, '') as namelist;
```

Comment: Rob Farley's solution no longer comes up the page just sits there loading indefinitely.  Can someone please POST the solution?  This is why linking to other people's sites doesn't provide a permanent solution

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I'm just using FOR XML PATH to concat strings together. I don't want &amp;

Comment: Note that the STUFF keyword is not relevant to removing the ampersand, but is used to remove the initial comma

Comment: Don't understand how this works - it would be a nice addition to explain the solution - but it works.

Answer (score 6):

Try this....

```
select 
  stuff( 
     (select ', <' + name + '>' 
     from sys.databases 
     where database_id > 4 
     order by name 
     for xml path(''), root('MyString'), type 
     ).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') 
   , 1, 2, '') as namelist;
```

Comment: Note that the STUFF keyword is not relevant to removing the ampersand, but is used to remove the initial comma