# How to concatenate distinct columns of otherwise duplicate rows into one row without using FOR XML PATH('')?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, for-xml-path

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            f1.CourseEventKey,
            STUFF
            (
                (
                    SELECT      '; ' + Title
                    FROM        (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT
                                                ces.CourseEventKey,
                                                f.Title
                                    FROM        CourseEventSchedule ces
                                    INNER JOIN  Facility f ON f.FacilityKey = ces.FacilityKey
                                    WHERE       ces.CourseEventKey IN
                                                (
                                                    SELECT      CourseEventKey
                                                    FROM        @CourseEvents
                                                )
                                ) f2
                    WHERE       f2.CourseEventKey = f1.CourseEventKey
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, ''
            )
FROM        (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                            ces.CourseEventKey,
                            f.Title
                FROM        CourseEventSchedule ces
                INNER JOIN  Facility f ON f.FacilityKey = ces.FacilityKey
                WHERE       ces.CourseEventKey IN
                            (
                                SELECT      CourseEventKey
                                FROM        @CourseEvents
                            )
            ) f1
```

It produces this result set:

```
CourseEventKey Titles
-------------- ----------------------------------
29             Test Facility 1
30             Memphis Training Room
32             Drury Inn &amp; Suites Creve Coeur
```

The data is accurate, but I can't have `FOR XML PATH('')` because it escapes certain special characters.

To be clear, I'm using `FOR XML PATH('')` because it is possible for records with the same `CourseEventKey` to have multiple `Facility` titles associated with them.

How can I retain the data returned by this query without using `FOR XML PATH('')`?

Comment: Which version of sql-server are you running? If it's 2012, then [`CONCAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) will be helpful in the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's 2008. It could be 2005. @Trafz

Comment: This link could prove helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270948/how-to-preserve-an-ampersand-while-using-for-xml-path-on-sql-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "for xml path('') )" section to "for xml path(''), root('root'), type).query('root').value ('.', 'varchar(max)')" this will unescape the characters correctly.

Sorry for the poor formatting but not at my computer right now. I can give a full example later if you need.

Comment: No, it is an XPath query, part of SQL xml. The "for xml" generates an xml data type, and so the text is xml escaped. The XPath query uses the SQL xml value function to convert that xml back to varchar, which will unescape the special xml characters.